# Sed: How to edit a line that have some contents needed to be remain after substitution?

Tags: sed

I have a site that need to made some mass edit, I used sed to perform most of the task but add the heading tag(`<h1>`, `<h2>`) is so tricky that I can't think up of a way to due with:

The pattern that I could guarantee is as follow:

```
<td class="content_subhd">Heading Name</td>
```

I want to change it to:

```
<td class="content_subhd"><h2>Heading Name</h2></td>
```

Where Heading Name is not static, it is different on each page and this is why I can use substitute to due with it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 tricks needed:

1. Use pattern grouping `\( ... \)` and reinsertion `\1`
2. Use a colon as pattern seperator instead of `/` to avoid excessive quoting

Result:

```
 sed 's:\(<td class="content_subhd">\)\(.*\)\(</td>\):\1<h2>\2</h2>\3:'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<td class="content_subhd">Heading Name</td>' | \
sed -r 's;(<td\s*class\s*=\s*"content_subhd"\s*>)([^<]+)(</td>);\1<h2>\2</h2>\3;'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
sed 's/\([^>]*>\)\(.*\)\(<.*\)/\1<h1>\2<\/h1>\3/'
         1         2     3
```

1. catches everything up to and including first `>`
2. catches the `Heading Name` and other possible content
3. catches everything after that